# com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android

I am suffering with these 2 problems saying :

```
Failed to install ImamAlsajadSayings.apk on device 'emulator-5554': 
No such file or directory ImamAlsajadSayings] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException:
No such file or directory
```

I have read that I need to clean my project. I did that and still the problem haven't solved. The apk file is there. I don't know what's is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was trying to run a modified version of my app while the emulator was still open. So it was not being installed.

I closed my emulator and run the app again and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Create another emulator in `AVD` Manager and try to run your application in the new emulator. Hope this might help you.

Or

Wait for the emulator to setup completely and then test your app. Also, leave your `AVD` open so you dont have to wait so long everytime you run your application.