# Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk (Hello World!) on device

Tags: android

First, sorry for my ignorance. I'm trying to make the HelloWorld app run following step by step the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html).
I can't load the app, as Android keeps showing me the message:

```
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] Performing mypackage.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyNexusOne'
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyNexusOne'
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-05-26 15:56:38 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] Performing mypackage.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
[2014-05-26 15:57:02 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!
```

At the beginning, I have the same problem like in this question:
[Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073046/waiting-for-home-android-process-acore-to-be-launched)
So I did as the suggested answer, *"right click on the project and click run as Android application once again"*. At the first time, Android showed me a window to select the device, which I chose the only one available 'emulator-5554'. After choosing and running, Android showed me the message above. From the second time I run it, Android showed me directly the message, and didn't show the window to choose the emulator again.

It seems I have the same problem like in this question:
[com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727797/com-android-ddmlib-syncexception-no-such-file-or-directory)
But none of the answers work for me.

In a desperate attempt, I already changed the ADB connection timeout to 10000ms.

Comment: The emulator is very very long to launch ... How many time do you have wait ?

Comment: At the beginning, Android keeps showing "Waiting for HOME" for about 20 minutes (I have a considerably strong Fedora machine). When I read the answer above, I run the app again after some seconds seeing "Waiting for HOME".

Comment: It says that there is no such file. In your question, you have mentioned HelloWorld.apk while the messages show MyFirstApp.apk

Comment: I'm sorry the title is wrong. It is MyFirstApp.apk, the app prints out "Hello World!" message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the apk is build without any issues but when eclipse is trying to install, it is not finding the "MyFirstApp.apk". 
Make sure the generated .apk file is in the "bin" directory. OR the eclipse is trying to read it from some other path.

Comment: Thanks, MyFirstApp.apk is in the "bin" directory. How do I know if eclipse is trying to read it from some other source.

Comment: Hey I was going through the logs again, looks like it found the .apk[Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'] but when it is trying to install it [Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory]. Can you try restarting the emulator or try with actual android device instead of  emulator.

Comment: I can't test it with real device :-) I'm using a "stupid" phone, Nokia 6020.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this question while trying to research why mine did the same thing.  When I changed the Eclipse 'Run Configurations' option from *'Launch Default Activity'* to Launch *'com.example.myfirstapp.MyActivity'*, the project was installed on the Android virtual device and happily loaded and ran properly.  Took a very, very long time to load the Virtual Device, as others have said.